# Opencv can't write video: cap_mjpeg_encoder.cpp:829: error: (-215)

Tags: opencv, video, opencv3.0

I use opencv to open a video, process frame by frame and write it back to a video. For some videos, this works fine, but for others, I got this wired error when I try to write the frames back to a video:

```
cv2.error: /home/xxx/Documents/opencv_videos/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_mjpeg_encoder.cpp:829: error: (-215) img.cols == width && img.rows == height && channels == 3 in function write
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('cut.avi')
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 25.0, (1280,720))

count = 0
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        processed_frame = PROCESS(frame)
        cv2.imwrite('temp.jpg',processed_frame)
        out.write(processed_frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
```

I can, however, use `cv2.imwrite` to write the process frame to a jpeg image on disk. Does anyone know where this error comes from? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it's coming from the `VideoWriter` instance. What's the `shape` of `processed_frame`?

Comment: Using `processed_frame.shape`, I got `(512, 1280, 3)`

Comment: Right, but that doesn't match the size you initialized the `VideoWriter` with...

Comment: But different video has different size, how can I handle all of them in a single system?

Comment: You could try to extract the frame size from the `VideoCapture` instance using the [`get`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aeb1644641842e6b104f244f049648f94) method. Second option is to lazy initialize `VideoWriter` after the first frame has been read out, and you know its size.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem!